# How to interpret units such as $m^{-2}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I'm doing a project of mangroves and found this chart
http://www.habitat.noaa.gov/coastalbluecarbon.html
It lists how much carbon mangroves and a few other ecosystems absorb but the chart uses m^-2/yr^-1 and I don't know what that means

Comment: Is it $\frac {m^{-2}}{yr^{-1}}$ or $\frac {m^2}{yr^1}$?  The first one doesn't make a whole lot of sense, because it would be far easier to write $\frac {yr}{m^2}$, also $\frac {m^2}{yr^1}$ makes more intuitive sense as a unit (metre's squared per year, or amount of area per year).

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming it's M2/yr but I don't know, the website I liked has a graph with the units I'm confused about

Comment: That's not $\frac {m^{-2}}{yr^{-1}} $, it's $m^{-2} yr^{-1} $.

Comment: Well what does that mean?

Comment: That graph is plotting the rate of carbon absorbed per unit area of land. Thus, a reading of $6{\rm g\,C\,yr^{\large{\hat{}}}-1\,m^{\large{\hat{}}}-2}$ would mean that at the site in question, each square meter of that land were absorbing 6 grams of carbon each year. Another way to write this would be $6{\rm g\,/\,m^2\,/\,yr}$ or, most conventionally $6{\rm g\,m^{-2}\,yr^{-1}}$. One uses circumflexes when the typesetting can't easily render exponents (as in 1980s era CRT computer terminals).

Comment: Oh, so it's a different to write that, ok. Thank you very much

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - You should make that an answer.

Comment: Copy the relevant part of the link here. Your question should be understable without click, it is a criterium here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question here seems to be what signs in exponents mean. It doesn't matter if the quantity is a physical parameter or a unit. A negative sign on the exponent means *divided by*, and could just as well have been written as a fraction.

- $a^4\qquad$ is $\qquad a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a$
- $a^3\qquad$ is $\qquad a\cdot a\cdot a$
- $a^2\qquad$ is $\qquad a\cdot a$
- $a^1\qquad$ is $\qquad a$
- $a^½\qquad$ is $\qquad \sqrt a$
- $a^⅓\qquad$ is $\qquad \sqrt[3] a$
- $a^0\qquad$ is $\qquad 1\qquad$ ([explained conveniently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878897/why-is-a-raised-to-the-power-of-zero-is-1) or [defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9703/how-do-i-explain-2-to-the-power-of-zero-equals-1-to-a-child), depending on who you ask)
- $a^{-1}\qquad$ is $\qquad \frac{1}{a}$
- $a^{-2}\qquad$ is $\qquad \frac{1}{a\cdot a}$
- $a^{-3}\qquad$ is $\qquad \frac{1}{a\cdot a\cdot a}$
- $a^{-4}\qquad$ is $\qquad \frac{1}{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a}$

That $a^{-1}$ really is the same as $\frac1a$ is quite obvious: for example, $a^3$ means "*we have three $a$'s*" while $\frac1{a^3}$ means "*we have three $a$'s less*". It makes sense to add a minus sign and write $a^{-3}$ when the term "removes" $a$'s.

Writing $a/b$ or $\frac ab$ means that we have one $a$ and "remove" one $b$. You could just as well write $a\cdot b^{-1}$. In your example with $\mathrm m^{-2}/\mathrm{yr}^{-1}$, the $\mathrm m^{-2}$ can therefore be written as a fraction $\frac1{\mathrm m^2}$ and the $\mathrm{yr}^{-1}$ also as a fraction $\frac1{\mathrm{yr}}$:

$$\mathrm m^{-2}/\mathrm{yr}^{-1}=\frac 1{\mathrm m^2}/\frac 1{\mathrm{yr}}$$

This is a double division. If you know the arithmetic rules, dividing by a fraction turns the fraction around:

$$\frac 1{\mathrm m^2}/\frac 1{\mathrm{yr}}=\frac 1{\mathrm m^2}\frac{\mathrm{yr}}1=\frac {\mathrm{yr}}{\mathrm m^2}$$

So we are talking about *years per square metre*. This does not make much physical sense in itself, but I can see in the comments that there is more to it.

---

If, as some comments suggest, the division line is a mistake and we actually have $\mathrm m^{-2}\mathrm{yr}^{-1}$, then there is no double division and we keep both fractions:

$$\mathrm m^{-2}\mathrm{yr}^{-1}=\frac 1{\mathrm m^{2}}\frac 1{\mathrm{yr}}=\frac 1{\mathrm m^{2}\mathrm{yr}}$$

So this is basically just a unit of *per square metre per year*.

Answer (score 2):

The units are $\rm g_C m^{-2} \text{yr}^{-1}$ which means "grammes of carbon per square metre per year". An exponent which is negative means it is being divided, which is the same as saying "per". In other words, how many grammes of carbon are being absorbed by each square metre of habitat in 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

That graph is plotting the rate of carbon absorbed per unit area of land. Thus, a reading of $6{\rm g\,C\,yr^{\large{\hat{}}}-1\,m^{\large{\hat{}}}-2}$ would mean that at the site in question, each square meter of that land were absorbing 6 grams of carbon each year. Another way to write this would be $6{\rm g\,/\,m^2/\,yr}$ or, most conventionally $6{\rm g\,m^{−2}\,yr^{−1}}$. One uses circumflexes when the typesetting can't easily render exponents (as was the case for in 1980s era CRT computer terminals).